# How to make Bootstrap Panel body with fixed height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap's `panel` to display text and image, but as the text grows, the body of the panel also increases. I want to know how to create the body with fixed height, e.g. 10 rows or at most 10 rows.  Here is my code:

```
<div class="span4">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">jhdsahfjhdfhs</div>
    <div class="panel-body">fdoinfds sdofjohisdfj</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide some code . You can fix the height of panel with the height property in css. @user3500605

Comment: @JPrakash it's common code, nothing special. How to use height?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can use `max-height` in an inline `style` attribute, as below:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">jhdsahfjhdfhs</div>
  <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 10;">fdoinfds sdofjohisdfj</div>
</div>
```

To use scrolling with content that overflows a given `max-height`, you can alternatively try the following:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">jhdsahfjhdfhs</div>
  <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 10;overflow-y: scroll;">fdoinfds sdofjohisdfj</div>
</div>
```

To restrict the height to a fixed value you can use something like this.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">jhdsahfjhdfhs</div>
  <div class="panel-body" style="min-height: 10; max-height: 10;">fdoinfds sdofjohisdfj</div>
</div>
```

Specify the same value for both `max-height` and `min-height` (either in pixels or in points – as long as it’s consistent).

You can also put the same styles in css class in a stylesheet (or a `style` tag as shown below) and then include the same in your tag. See below:

**Style Code:**

```
.fixed-panel {
  min-height: 10;
  max-height: 10;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**Apply Style :**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">jhdsahfjhdfhs</div>
  <div class="panel-body fixed-panel">fdoinfds sdofjohisdfj</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought inline styles were frowned upon?

Comment: after minimizing the height. My Heading text is hiding. Suggest solution

Comment: In my case I had to specify the units explicitly, for the browser to honour the `max-height` value.

Comment: why is setting min-height and max-height to the same value better than simply height?

Comment: @sunew: because they are limiting the div in range as height just points to the exact value but does not specify what is happening on overflowing content

Comment: This gives "invalid property value" on chrome. 10 is not a valid value for max-height. Try 10px and it should work.

Answer (score 24):

**HTML :**

```
<div class="span4">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">jhdsahfjhdfhs</div>
    <div class="panel-body panel-height">fdoinfds sdofjohisdfj</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.panel-height {
  height: 100px; / change according to your requirement/
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however the solution from Benison is better so I can only vote his answer :)