# how to keep two div, one with text and the other one with an image, side by side, without one expanding vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

If you scroll to the portfolio section you ll see what I'm talking about. the screen res of my workstation is 1600x900 which renders the site perfectly with the amount of text i have in the content div. However if i make the browser narrower, the div gets longer which i don't want that happen. I can't figure out how to get the div to not expand pass the height of the image so that there won't be any space below the image when users re-size the browser. Please advise.

```
<div class="row" id="portfolio">
<div class="span12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>this is the first project</h2>
        <p1>Phasellus vitae sem eu lacus bibendum iaculis eu sit amet augue. Ut aliquet imperdiet sem, vel imperdiet ipsum. Donec ligula elit, vestibulum efficitur nisi non, posuere ornare quam. Ut tempor finibus commodo. Nulla commodo eros nec diam lobortis
          tempus. Nam et purus erat. Nunc metus odio, porttitor in tempus non, viverra at velit. Vestibulum ut ultrices eros.</p1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://goo.gl/LlkQ2N" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://goo.gl/q00U2p" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>this is the second project</h2>
        <p1>Phasellus vitae sem eu lacus bibendum iaculis eu sit amet augue. Ut aliquet imperdiet sem, vel imperdiet ipsum. Donec ligula elit, vestibulum efficitur nisi non, posuere ornare quam. Ut tempor finibus commodo. Nulla commodo eros nec diam lobortis
          tempus. Nam et purus erat. Nunc metus odio, porttitor in tempus non, viverra at velit. Vestibulum ut ultrices eros.</p1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>this is the third project</h2>
        <p1>Phasellus vitae sem eu lacus bibendum iaculis eu sit amet augue. Ut aliquet imperdiet sem, vel imperdiet ipsum. Donec ligula elit, vestibulum efficitur nisi non, posuere ornare quam. Ut tempor finibus commodo. Nulla commodo eros nec diam lobortis
          tempus. Nam et purus erat. Nunc metus odio, porttitor in tempus non, viverra at velit. Vestibulum ut ultrices eros.</p1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://goo.gl/yvLkOv" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

DEMO http://codepen.io/mrfishball/pen/QyEqwP (scroll to the portfolio section)

Comment: I didn't down vote, but do find the question unclear. This previous post might help answer your question: [How to make Bootstrap Panel body with fixed height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450010/how-to-make-bootstrap-panel-body-with-fixed-height)

Comment: Like this? http://codepen.io/dirtysmith/pen/zrwvPr

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most beautiful piece of code - optimally you add your own classes to the markup, but this is the code you are looking for I believe:

```
#portfolio .row {
  position: relative;
}

#portfolio .col-md-4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#portfolio .row > div:first-of-type.col-md-4 {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
}

#portfolio .row > div:last-of-type.col-md-8 {
  margin-left: 33.333333%
}

#portfolio .image {
height: 100%;
}

#portfolio .image > img {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGWYKV

Comment: Thanks! finally there's no space around the image but now i have another problem. when the browser gets narrow enough(mobile view) the text gets on top or under the image. :(

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. You should wrap the new css in a media query targeting the md size and up. Something like this @media (min-width:768px) { ... The code ... }